# TypeError: range[i][0].slice is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script

I just want to know why my script doesn't work I have a sheet with inventory data something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHb2d.png) and I want to slice column G till 4 characters but only works when my range is G2443 I want that works with range G2:G; heres my script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGim6.png)

I tried change the range but doesn't work.

Comment: Kindly [edit] to post text as text and not as images.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Just add "" before and after Your string before using 'slice'

```
"" + range[i][0] + ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet, from your error message of `TypeError: range[i][0].slice is not a function`, I'm worried that in your situation, the values except for string might be included in the values of `range`. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
newArray.push([range[i][0].slice(0, 4)]);
```

#### To:

```
newArray.push([range[i][0].toString().slice(0, 4)]);
```

or

```
newArray.push([typeof range[i][0] == "string" ? range[i][0].slice(0, 4) : null]);
```